# Tracing back rare error

Tags: r, cluster-computing, multicore

I'm running a code which takes very long to compute. I made my code parallel using `foreach()%dopar%` and run in on the cluster.

It runs generally fine but sometimes crashes and I get the following error :
`Error in { : task 4 failed - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
Calls: %dopar% -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted`

Now it says Execution halted but only for this particular core so the others keep running and at the end it fails to output but doesn't tell me before hand.
I guess it's a problem with an `if` statement. I tried simulating the code on my computer but it is so rare that I can't simulate it.

The code runs easily 100 hours doing as many as 100 000 loops and only one of them will fail.

My questions are : Can I traceback where the error was? (I run the code on a cluster so I don't have all the nice Rstudio stuff)
Also, is it possible to still output from a `foreach()` loop even if one of the tasks crashed?
Or perhaps any method people use so that I can make the crash happen on my computer?

I can write the code if needed, please ask if it helps.

Comment: wrap your computation in a try(). Then you'll have all the results and be able to investigate the problem

Comment: @KarlForner : I can't seem to make `try` work. It keeps complaining about `Unexpected symbols` when it's just my code... Is there a special way to use it? I'm not familiar with it at all.

Comment: `try` or `trycatch` is good advice.  Another possibility is to log the *input* (i.e. the j-th data subset) being used on every parallel call, so that you can narrow down the piece of data that caused the problem.  In the meantime, make sure you've got validation code in your function, such as checking that `length(something) >0` and `!is.na(something)` are `TRUE` before applying `if(something)` .

Comment: Weird. Normally you just do res <- try(compute_stuff(args)) instead of res <- compute_stuff(args)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreach ".errorhandling" argument is intended to help in this situation. If you want foreach to pass errors through, then use `.errorhandling="pass"`. If you want it to filter out errors (which reduces the length of the result), then use `.errorhandling="remove"`. The default value is "stop" which throws an error indicating which task failed.

Unfortunately, most parallel backends don't support tracebacks, but doMPI does. You simply call "startMPIcluster" with `verbose=TRUE`, and the traceback will be written to the log file of the worker that had the error. Here's an example that generates an error on task 42:

```
suppressMessages(library(doMPI))
cl <- startMPIcluster(4, verbose=TRUE)
registerDoMPI(cl)
g <- function(i) {
  if (i == 42) {
    if (NULL) cat('hello, world\n')
  }
  7
}
f <- function(i) g(i)
r <- foreach(i=1:50, .errorhandling='pass') %dopar% f(i)
print(r)
closeCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

Since it uses `.errorhandling="pass"`, the script runs to completion, with an error object returned in element 42 of the result list. In addition, one of the log files contains a traceback of the error (along with many other messages):

```
waiting for a taskchunk...
executing taskchunk 42 containing 1 tasks
error executing task: argument is of length zero
traceback (most recent call first):
> g(i)
> f(i)
> eval(expr, envir, enclos)
> eval(expr, envir)
> executeTask(taskchunk$argslist[[1]])
> executeTaskChunk(cl$workerid, taskchunk, envir, err, cores)
returning error results for taskchunk 42
```

Unfortunately, doMPI is mostly used on Linux systems, so this isn't helpful to most Mac and Windows users.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to use doMPI at the beginning instead of foreach, unfortunately the linux cluster isn't able to install it. I asked the administrator to do it a couple of months ago but no answer :-( Would `.errorhandling = "pass"` put NA instead of the answer and keep on going? I'll give it a try but the error is very random and rare so might be coming back in a couple of days.

Comment: Unless I'm getting confused with Rmpi? That's the error I get when I try installing it https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2011-May/000977.html

Comment: @TAllieri I updated the answer to say that an error object is returned in the result list when using .errorhandling="pass".

Comment: @TAllieri doMPI depends on Rmpi, and Rmpi is the tricky package to install (if you aren't using Debian packages). Still, I've had no trouble with it when building it on Open MPI, especially since you don't need to get all of the Rmpi worker startup scripts working just to use Rmpi from doMPI.